# iOS index 2 beyond bounds error while inserting rows

Tags: ios, uitableview, insert, tableview

I have a UITableView that is static and configured through storyboard. I am trying to insert some rows during didSelectRowAtIndexPath using insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: and am getting the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   1]'.

I have implemented numberOfRowsInSection but am still getting this error everytime. Does it have to do with the table being static at not dynamic? Thanks.

```
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    if (indexPath.row == 1) { // Map Type Cell

        self.isSelectingMapType = YES;

        NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:1], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:1], nil];
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        //[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 1) {
        if (self.isSelectingMapType == YES) {
            return 6;
        }
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a quick look at [Apple's Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1) regarding how table views behave within an updates block.

> Deletion and reloading operations within an animation block specify which rows and sections in **the original table** should be removed or reloaded; insertions specify which rows and sections should be added to the resulting table. The index paths used to identify sections and rows follow this model.

You cannot use those index paths because they are not yet present in the table.
Since you check `isSelectingMapType` in `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you should be able to simply ask the table view to reload to achieve your desired results.

Comment: That makes sense. I know I can achieve it by just calling reloadData but is there anyway to achieve the animation effect as if using insertRows?

Comment: Using `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation` as you have in your snippet should suffice. A small prototype I stuck together worked nicely just using that. There's no need to animate the individual rows then.

Comment: Alright thanks. I got that to work! One other thing, when the reload is triggered, the original 2 cells disappear and the 4 new appear below. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

I use storyboard for all my apps but have never tried inserting rows into UITableView with static cells. What I have done was to create all the rows that were needed in storyboard and hide/show them programmatically instead of inserting them.

First, create all the cells that you wanted in storyboard. Then, modify the code as follows:

```
if (indexPath.section == 1) 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    { 
        self.isSelectingMapType = YES;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that. I just like the animations. Anyway to add animation to it?